# User Authentication With Google OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, phpstorm, php-7, symfony4

I am new to Symfony 4, so I want to make an authentication system with Google OAuth 2.0.

I am following the instructions on this link: https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle. Everything was working as expected till I tried the Authenticating with guard part here https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle#authenticating-with-guard, which generates the following error:

> The autoloader expected class "App\MyGoogleAuthenticator" to be defined in file "/home/user1234/PhpstormProjects/test_symf_01/vendor/composer/../../src/MyGoogleAuthenticator.php".
>   The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in /home/user1234/PhpstormProjects/test_symf_01/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/home/user1234/PhpstormProjects/test_symf_01/config/services.yaml").

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Where this error appears? In PhpStorm editor (inspection)? Or when running the code itself?

Comment: @VladLuchansky When running the code itslef